# Running a class with the name within in a variable at run-time in JAVA

Tags: java, reflection

I have been learning Java and over the last few weeks I have created a bunch of classes for practice purposes. It got into my head that it would be cool to create a class that allowed me to see a list of all the classes that I have created and run them by choosing the class I want.

The way I did it and how far I have gone:

- I read into a `HashMap<Integer,String>` a list of all my classes with a SimpleFileVisitor.
- From this list the user can chose a file by entering the number associated with the class.
- A string is returned with the class name.

Now here comes the issue.

I end up for example with a string called `Clock.class`.
I want to run this. How?

Let's say that I knew the class I wanted to run. I could simple use `Clock.main()`
The issue here is that I will not know which class to run until run-time, so I am lost.

I have been toying around with the Reflection API. I am able to instantiate an object of the Clock.class but nothing happens.

Maybe I should not be using reflection at all? Maybe there is a simpler way?

This is where I am stuck, I hope someone can enlighten me. :)

Comment: Are the class files on your classpath?

Comment: Your note at the bottom is irrelevant. People in this site will *judge* that, there's no need to add such note. Apart of that, your question seems fine and very clear. I would recommend using `ProcessBuilder` to execute `java` and pass the path of the `.class` file to execute it.

Comment: If you can instantiate it then you already have all the stuff you need. If you want to run a static method, call it on the class. If you want to run an instance method, same, but on the instance. I might consider a slightly different approach, like using instances that implement an interface, and calling the interface method directly.

Answer (score 2):

You could use reflection to call the main method of the class:

```
Class<?> cls = Class.forName("package.path.yourClassName");
Method m = cls.getMethod("main", String[].class); //mandatory signature for main()
String[] params = null; // any params on the call?
m.invoke(null, (Object) params);
```

Note: The first parameter of `invoke()` would be the instance on which you'd like to invoke the call. But static mehtods don't belong to instances, therefore use `null`.

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I was going for. It works perfectly. Thank you so much :)

Answer (score 1):

You have the File path to your class files from traversing via `SimpleFileVisitor`. Store the file name and path in a Map. When user chooses lets say  `Clock.class` get path corresponding to it and start another java process.

Simply do

```
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("/pathToJDK/bin/java", pathToClassFile);
```

You can play around with I/O and Error streams like -

```
InputStream inputStream= process .getErrorStream();
//print this stream
```

Comment: Should be `/pathToJDK/bin/java`. Btw, it might be convenient to determine classpath and JVM location at runtime to correctly invoke the JVM.

Comment: yeah sorry for the typo. As for finding JVM location you can use the following code - [Finding Java home programatically from Java program](http://opensourceforgeeks.blogspot.in/2014/11/finding-java-home-programatically-from.html) worked for me in similar problem.

Comment: I don't think it is necessary to use that approach as the JVM is usually sufficient, no need to find an alternative JDK (which offers its own JVM). Simply use the system properties `java.home` and `java.class.path`.

Comment: Thanks everyone for taking the time.

I was able to achieve my goal following dognose's instructions but for the sake of learning I went to test your method @Aniket Thakur and still_learning

I get an error using these parameters for exec(), pathtojava and pathtofile. I looked this up and it seems I should pass an array with the command and any parameters. So I am guessing something like:

`params[] = {"pathToDK/bin/java","Clock"};`

Would this be correct? I have actually tried it. No errors but nothing happens.